# Show that square of any odd natural number is congruent to 1 mod 8.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science

How can we prove that the square of any odd natural number is congruent to 1 mod 8?

Comment: Hint: Every odd number can be expressed in the form $2k+1$

Comment: $\mathbb Z_8^\times$ is isomorphic to the Klein 4 group.

Answer (score 1):

Squares of odd numbers modulo $8$:
$$
1^2 \equiv 1 \\
3^2 = 9 \equiv 1 \\
5^2 = 25 \equiv 1 \\
7^2 = 49 \equiv 1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Any odd number can be written in the form $2n+1$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
$$ (2n+1)^2 = 4n(n+1)+1. $$
The second term is equivalent to $1$ modulo $8$ (obviously). The first term is divisible by $4$, so it is either $0$ or $4$ modulo $8$. But one of $n$, $n+1$ is always even, so $2 \mid n(n+1)$, so in fact the first term is divisible by $8$. Hence 
$$ (2n+1)^2 = 4n(n+1)+1 \equiv 1 \pmod 8. $$